# Division and Multiplication not working on python 3.5.1

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters “done”. Once “done” is entered, print out the total, count, and average of the numbers.

finding the total, count, and average isn't showing up, can someone please figure this out and put the full code in Python 3.5.1? much appreciated

here is my code:

```
    numbers = []
while True:
    raw_input = input('Enter a whole number: ')
    try:
        numbers.append(int(raw_input))
    except ValueError:
        if raw_input is not None and raw_input.lower() == ('done'):
            break
        else:
            print ('Invalid input.')

length = len * (numbers)
total = sum * (numbers)
average = total/count

print ('Total is'), total
print ('Count is'), length
print ('Average is'), average
```

Comment: Why are you doing `len * (numbers)` and `sum * (numbers)`? That's not how function calls work. Presumably you want `len(numbers)` and `sum(numbers)`; similarly, the parens you used for `print` are too narrow, guessing you want `print('Total is', total)` and so on; `print` in Py3 is a function taking arguments, not a special statement; the parens must surround all arguments.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code you need to include the variables as arguments to the print function. For example:

```
print('Total is', total)
```